# How to Run Heap Spraying Analysis in Virtual Machine

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, virtual-machine, windbg

Over the past few weeks I have been working on a project to detect heap-spraying attacks on applications. To do this, I have been developing a binary classifier to discern the difference between the two. To get features from the application heap, I used a combination of WinDbg and PYKD (more info here: https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/heap-tracing-with-windbg-and-python/). It collects features by running the application and attaching it to my python script.

The problem comes with detecting malicious features. With a binary classifier, I will need to give it hundreds of examples of malicious heap-spraying attacks. The problem is I collect features by actually running the program. How can I do this without harming my computer? I realize I can use a virtual machine, but I do not want to create a new virtual machine for every test of malicious features as this is simply too tedious.

Comment: I understand. However, the problem is there are no databases of non malicious heap spraying websites. There are plenty of databases of malicious heap spraying websites. And since a classifier needs hundreds of examples of heap spraying, I am unable to find non-malicious examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO you have 2 options:

- avoid the malicious part of the attack
- automate the VM "creation" process

### Avoid the malicious part of the attack

My understanding of an attack with heap spraying consists of 2 phases:

1. the heap is sprayed, e.g. for a browser by loading pictures which actually contain code
2. an exploit is used, causing undesired behavior which makes the IP (instruction pointer) point somewhere to the sprayed heap

I think you would like to detect the heap spraying phase before the exploit actually causes harm.

You could take an existing attack and modify the code in a way that it e.g. launches the calculator instead of the evil EXE. For example, the JS code posted on the [website you linked](https://labs.mwrinfosecurity.com/blog/heap-tracing-with-windbg-and-python/) seems to be harmless. It uses lots of NOPs and the string `CORELAN` which doesn't seem to result in valid assembly.

This, of course, requires a deep understanding of the exploit. You'll probably need assembler language knowledge to do that. And you would want to do this for many exploits if you need 100s of examples.

On the other hand side, if you understand this on assembler level, you could derive several different examples from 1 successful attack. You could start notepad instead, you can insert more or less `nop` operations, you can use a COM object or ActiveX etc. It might give you many harmless examples.

### Automate virtual machine

Virtual machines have a feature called snapshot. Such a snapshot can be taken while the VM was running, so it gets into a known state very fast.

This process can even be automated, i.e. you can write a script for you that

- resets a VM into a known state
- copies files to the VM
- runs programs on the VM (e.g. the Browser)
- run the remote debugger in the VM
- ...

Have a look at [vSphere Automation SDK](https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-automation-sdk/). Since you run this script on the host, you could also include other steps such as

- start the debugger
- script the debugger (e.g. with PyKD)
- run everything for limited amount of time, e.g. 30 seconds
- collect the results (crash dump or similar)
- shut down the VM

Be aware that some viruses might be able to break out of a VM, e.g. through that SME bug where you got access to ring -1.